# Where and how does the assembly references are serialized or deserialized in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk

I've got stuck with a problem. I've an BizTalk 2010 application which references a Third party Schema dll. Our Architect told us not to directly reference it as it'll take more time to serialize this huge around 9MB dll which will cause Biztalk work more.

Since this Third part dll is a schema dll it'll be deployed to MgmtDb under any of the applications prior any other app deployment. Our orchestration messages has messagetypes which are referenced from this schema dll.

What I want to know is where excatly this serialization of this external dll taking place as the this dll already been deployed and Orchestration instance can reference this against any request messages which comes in.

Do serialization happen for each message which creates an orchestration instance.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While its true that the referenced assembly will be added into MgmtDB, AFAIK it is only metadata about the assembly and the artifacts in it which is added, e.g.

```
use BizTalkMgmtDb
select * from dbo.bts_assembly
... dbo.bts_orchestration
... dbo.bt_DocumentSpec
etc.
```

Possibly he/she is refering to instances of messages created from schema classes in the assembly (and are stored in the messagebox). But the size of the messages will be determined by the size of the data in it, not by the size of the assembly.

Since you seem to need the referenced message schemas, there isn't much option but to reference it in your new project (e.g. unless you have the source to the 3rd party assembly where you could refactor it and split it into several smaller assemblies). The 3rd party assembly needs to be deployed on your BizTalk servers and signed and GACed.

However if this referenced schema assembly also contains other artifacts like custom classes used in orchestrations as variables, these classes will also need to be [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418739%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) as soon as the orchestration hits a dehydration point (to avoid this you would need to scope the variables out before the dehydration and / or use an atomic scope to prevent BizTalk from dehydrating at all, but this is generally a bad idea as it will limit scalability)

Answer (score 0):

Your Architect has made an incorrect assumption about when BizTalk performs validation of a Document against its defined Schema.

Validating a large Document against a hefty Schema, such as an EDIFACT or OASIS, can take a lot of resources.  BizTalk therefore will not validate an incoming Document against its relevant schema unless you explicitly ask it to do so in the Receive Pipeline.  By default, most Pipeline components will have their 'ValidateDocument' property set to 'False'.  BizTalk will therefore only perform Document recognition, based on the namespace and root node, and this is done while stream-reading the first couple of hundred bytes of the document stream.

So, you can freely 'reference' the third party DLL, the only performance penalty will be at compile and deployment time.  If, for some reason, you need to validate a Document against this Schema, you would need to have it in the Management DB regardless.